# CSS code not affecting HTML document

Tags: html, css

I promise I've looked for an answer on here before asking.

I'm in an HTML course at school, and our final project for the unit is to make a multi framed webpage. In the main.htm file, I want the description to say "**About**" while facing on a 90 degree angle to the left of the text. I looked online, and it needs to use CSS, no problem, so I go to W3 Schools to find out how to properly use CSS. The problem is the notepad doc I'm using ignores the CSS completely.

Here's the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>

<HEAD>
  <STYLE>
    body {
      Background-color: #ffffff Font-Family: "Tw Cen MT";
    }
    h1 {
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
      ​
    }
  </STYLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

  <h1>The Pawnshop</h1>
  <h3>is a buy and sell eccomerse site. Send us information if you want to sell, or check out our store 
page if you're looking to buy.<h3>

</BODY>
</HTML>

​
```

The odd thing is when I test it online, and even when I try it in the code snippit, it works perfectly (aside from the sideways text being in the center which is a non-issue for now).

I'm editing in a notepad document and testing in Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ might make a good starting point

Comment: do yourself a favor and DON'T use the m$-specific css extensions. IE's market share is dropping rapidly into "rounding error" ranges. use proper STANDARD css, and don't get into the habit of consulting w3fools. they're a horrible resource

Comment: @MarcB upvote you got, for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include `-webkit-transform`, `-o-transform`,  `-moz-transform`, `transform` for other browsers to support transform

```css
    
    body {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Tw Cen MT";
    }
    h1 {
      position:absolute;
      left:0px;
      Top:20px;
      width:300px;
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
      ​
    }
```

```html
  <h1>The Pawnshop</h1>
  <h3>is a buy and sell eccomerse site. Send us information if you want to sell, or check out our store 
page if you're looking to buy.<h3>
```

Comment: `-ms-` is a microsoft prefix. Not Firefox. That would be `-moz-`.

Comment: Have you? Read the first line of your answer again :)

Comment: Finally, Now I have :)

Answer (score 1):

Dont forget this:

```
h1{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: all current browsers support this property without prefixes: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform and prefixes are abandoned for future releases. Just use one rule without prefix.

Comment: @Paulie_D just a example

Answer (score 0):

I can see many mistakes and not-following guidelines in your code.

```
body {
  Background-color: #ffffff Font-Family: "Tw Cen MT";
}
```

There are actually 2 rules:

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-family: "Tw Cen MT";
}
```

`-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);` this will work only on IE, because of `-ms-` prefix.
Take a look at corrected version: https://jsfiddle.net/oeqr3m6m/ (I've changed background color to be visible).

And as @slawrence10 says, add `type="text/css"` to your `style` tag.

Even if it works, please use small letters for css and html code.